# displaying plot in shiny. Error: Warning: Error in seq.default: 'from' must be a finite number

Tags: r, shiny

I am new to shiny and I am creating an app to calculate p values from a normal distribution. My app.r file looks like this:

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)

# Define UI
ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Normal Distribution Calculator"),
  
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      numericInput("mean", "Mean:", value = 0),
      numericInput("sd", "Standard Deviation:", value = 1),
      numericInput("score_a", "Score A:", value = 0),
      conditionalPanel(
        condition = "input.tail == 'both'",
        numericInput("score_b", "Score B:", value = 0)
      ),
      selectInput("tail", "Tail(s) to find:", choices = c("upper", "lower", "both")),
      actionButton("calculate", "Calculate")
    ),
    
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput("plot"),
      textOutput("p_value")
    )
  )
)

# Define server logic
server <- function(input, output) {
  output$p_value <- renderText({
    req(input$calculate)
    
    mean_val <- input$mean
    sd_val <- input$sd
    score_a <- input$score_a
    score_b <- ifelse(input$tail == "both", input$score_b, NA)
    
    if (input$tail == "upper") {
      p_value <- pnorm(score_a, mean = mean_val, sd = sd_val, lower.tail = FALSE)
    } else if (input$tail == "lower") {
      p_value <- pnorm(score_a, mean = mean_val, sd = sd_val, lower.tail = TRUE)
    } else {
      p_value <- pnorm(score_a, mean = mean_val, sd = sd_val, lower.tail = TRUE) +
        (1 - pnorm(score_b, mean = mean_val, sd = sd_val, lower.tail = TRUE))
    }
    
    paste("P-value:", round(p_value, 4))
  })
  
  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    req(input$calculate)
    
    mean_val <- input$mean
    sd_val <- input$sd
    score_a <- input$score_a
    score_b <- ifelse(input$tail == "both", input$score_b, NA)
    
    x <- seq(min(score_a, score_b, mean_val - 4 * sd_val), 
             max(score_a, score_b, mean_val + 4 * sd_val), 
             length.out = 1000)
    
    ggplot() +
      geom_line(aes(x = x, y = y), color = "blue") +
      geom_area(aes(x = ifelse(input$tail == "lower" | input$tail == "both", 
                               ifelse(x <= score_a, x, NA), NA), y = y), 
                fill = "red", alpha = 0.5) +
      geom_area(aes(x = ifelse(input$tail == "upper" | input$tail == "both", 
                               ifelse(x >= score_a, x, NA), NA), y = y), 
                fill = "green", alpha = 0.5) +
      labs(x = "Score", y = "Density", 
           title = "Normal Distribution with Shaded Areas",
           subtitle = paste("Mean:", mean_val, "SD:", sd_val)) +
      theme_minimal()
  })
}

# Run the application
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

when I run the app, it seems that it is correctly calculating the p values, however the plot is not displayed and I obtain the following error: Warning: Error in seq.default: 'from' must be a finite number.

Any help would be much appreciated.

I was expecting to display the normal curve with the area under curved in color. I am unsure what to do next.

Comment: Perhaps you should consider defining `y`.

Comment: I suggest you do a few things: (1) restart R, and do not load all of the data that you currently have in your environment. which may mean either not-loading `.Rdata` or not-running `.Rprofile` if present in your directory; (2)  add `browser()` after the `req(.)` in your `output$plot` block; (3) run the shiny app locally, then step through each line of code, finding errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's probably because `input$tail` is not `"both"` so `score_b` is `NA`:

```r
    score_b <- ifelse(input$tail == "both", input$score_b, NA)
    
    x <- seq(min(score_a, score_b, mean_val - 4 * sd_val), 
             max(score_a, score_b, mean_val + 4 * sd_val), 
             length.out = 1000)
```

Indeed, `min(2, NA, 4)` returns `NA`, and `seq(NA, ...)` returns the error you get. I don't know what you want to do, but maybe

```r
min(score_a, score_b, mean_val - 4 * sd_val, na.rm = TRUE)
```

And as noted by @YBS, you have to define `y`.